# accordion faq in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, accordion, markup

I would like to make a simple collapsible faq in wordpress.  There are accordion menu plugins out there that offer way more features than I need.  But I'm having trouble getting things to look right with the Simple Content Reveal plugin.

I'm ready to try writing my own jquery code for the first time.  I will need step by step instructions, or a link to same.

I will need a streamlined way of creating the markup for the faq.  An example of an inefficient way of creating the markup:

id="id1" etc.

id="id2" etc.

(taken from the markup for Simple Content Reveal)

In other words, I want to be able to go from a bunch of questions and answers in notepad to the markup for the collapsible faq without too much fussy copy and paste fiddling.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the [accoridian in the JQuery framework](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)? It's easy to use and should give you want you need.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://oraguide.com - It's a similar concept but everything is streamlined / hosted in the cloud.  It runs directly on the page as a floating div.[image: OraGuide - Website Help]